# How to highlight Java code at certain lines using prism.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, prism.js

Prism.js highlight line numbers not working. After a lot of trouble-shooting, it seems the absolute positioning of the highlight divs are overlapping each other (See figure[image: prism css]). This is the page I use to download prism.js: https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-dark&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript+c+cpp+java+javadoclike+javadoc&plugins=line-highlight+line-numbers+highlight-keywords

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="code-block">
<pre data-line="1-8, 10" data-start="31"><code class="language-java">public AlignmentResults unMarshallAlignmentResult(File alignmentFile) {
AlignmentResults alignmentResults;
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlignmentResults.class);
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    alignmentResults = (AlignmentResults) unmarshaller.unmarshal(alignmentFile);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    alignmentResults = null;
}
return alignmentResults;}</code>
</pre>
```

When the webpage loads, it looks like figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXc4G.png):
[image: highlight showing up when page loads]. Currently, lines 1-8 (31-38), and 10 (41) should be highlighted.

If I zoom my browser window, a more defined highlight appears but it is only at line 1 (or all of the highlights are stacked at line 1). 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Old answer deleted. Completely new answer:

---

The offset works differently than (I) expected.

Their online example is:

```
<pre data-line="43" data-line-offset="40" ...
```

And the *3rd line* is highlighted. The offset is 40, so count to 43 (a 3-count): 41, 42, 43 -- the 3rd line is highlighted.

In yours,

```
<pre data-line="1-8, 10" data-start="31">
```

the offset is 31, but you want to start highlighting at line 1. What's happening is, the highlighter goes ***backwards*** to find line 1, which is ***up*** 30 (or 31) lines.

Make sure the `data-line`s are greater than the `data-start` if using offset or data-start.

If I'm not mistaken yours should be:

```
<pre data-line="31-38, 40" data-line-offset="31">
```

Comment: No, that's not the reason for the error. I tried the offset as well. It looks like it's more of a positioning issue as I had shown in the second image above. In some cases, the line marker appears as a line in the margin, but when zoomed, it appears to stack the line markers on top of each other.

Comment: I fiddled with some live markup and rewrote my answer from scratch. Hth now.

Comment: Played with this some more and it's still not quite what I thought. And there is a difference between `data-start` and `data-line-offset`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it with a few modifications to the prism.css file to stretch the highlights across the screen. ``code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {...width:100%;
 display:block;}``